# How Can I Boot My PenDrive Linux using Parallels (Mac OS X)

Tags: linux, macos, mac, parallels

I have a persistent Ubuntu 10.04 installation on a 8GB PenDrive that I use to boot on Windows computers. However I cannot boot this setup from my Mac. (Will look into using rEFit) I have been trying, unsuccessfully, to get Parallels (v. 5) to boot from my PenDrive, however, there is no option to boot from usb. Does anyone have any insights?